# google map api with json data

Tags: json, api

can anyone show me an example of how to set a google map api in user-editable shape with json data.

```
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 44.5452, lng: -78.5389},
      zoom: 9
    });

    var bounds = {
      north: 44.599,
      south: 44.490,
      east: -78.443,
      west: -78.649
    };

    // Define a rectangle and set its editable property to true.
    var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      bounds: bounds,
      editable: true
    });
    rectangle.setMap(map);
  }
</script>
```

i'm looking for how to set a bounds variable with json data.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: no, i have json data surrounding a place, i'm looking for how to set the bounds variable for that.

Comment: The `bounds` variable is right there. Just change it to whatever you need. What json data do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Since you copied part of the example, I'll paste complete one

```
 <div id="map"></div>
 <script>
  // This example adds a user-editable rectangle to the map.
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 44.5452, lng: -78.5389},
      zoom: 9
    });

    var bounds = {
      north: 44.599,
      south: 44.490,
      east: -78.443,
      west: -78.649
    };

    // Define a rectangle and set its editable property to true.
    var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      bounds: bounds,
      editable: true
    });
    rectangle.setMap(map);
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Make sure you have the `div` element with `id="map"` so the map will show. Next you should get an API key from Google to use the map API (if you haven't got one allready) and replace `YOUR_API_KEY` with the key you receive.

Comment: bounds is json data in a way... Can you add an example of the data you have to your question?